# Is this an oxymoron?

Tags: semantics

*Purchase* is a thing that has been bought.

*Refunded*: past participle of “refund.”

Is ***refunded purchase*** an oxymoron?

Similar to: “[refunded contributions](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/filing-ssf-reports/refunded-contributions/)”

Comment: Saying *“refunded bought thing” is an oxymoron* doesn't really make sense in English. A ["refunded purchase"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+refunded+purchase%22) (very uncommon) would refer to a "purchase" (an act of buying something) that has been refunded. Which isn't quite the same thing as a ["purchase refund"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+purchase+refund%22) - a "refund" made in respect of some earlier act of purchasing.

Comment: "A purchase" can also represent the action involved, not just the object bought.  If anything, that's the more common interpretation in my idiolect.  "A refunded purchase" is *a refunded act of having bought something.*  But, even with your original interpretation, what's oxymoronic about "a refunded thing that was bought"?

Comment: Surely the _price_ is refunded (in exchange for the item being returned)?

Answer (score 2):

A change in state of something over time isn't typically considered an oxymoron, since there is no self-contradiction. An oxymoron implies that something has contradictory qualities A and B, but it doesn't very well describe something that has changed over time from quality A to quality B.

A burned-down building is not actually a building any more, a toppled regime is no longer a regime, a retired baseball player does not play baseball, and a refunded purchase isn't a purchase after all. None of these imply that the object in question had contradictory properties at any point in time, just that they had some property at one time and now exhibit an opposite quality. A refunded purchase was at one point a purchase, but now it is not - it doesn't imply that the transaction was both a purchase and not a purchase at the same time.

Comment: Purchase creates ownership. Refund cancels the ownership but the purchase has still happened. Same pattern as wedding / marriage / divorce; divorce ends the marriage but the wedding has happened and cannot be removed from history.